# how can we convert .txt file into a csv(Table) using python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a ".txt" file into a csv using python. So here I have converted a EDi 835 files into a csv(Table). And now I am trying to convert EDI 837 files into csv files. Below I have converted 835 file in csv using python library 'edi_835_parser' So now i am trying to convert edi_837 but i am not able to convert this in csv. So please any help is appriciated.

```
import edi_835_parser
from edi_835_parser import parse
path1 = '~/Desktop/files/EDI835POutput-20210804-012620-1.txt'

transaction_sets1 = parse(path1)
print(transaction_sets1)
data1 = transaction_sets1.to_dataframe()
print(data1)
```

- 

So here I am getting the output in csv table format. So the same i need in 837 file
*

Comment: I'd suggest that you play around with https://github.com/albmarin/badX12, which gives you a JSON-file that you can then read convert to a csv-file. I don't have a X12-file myself to try it on though.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/michaelachrisco/Electronic-Interchange-Github-Resources) you can find your parsers and see the `Python` tree [lab/parse-edi](https://hiplab.mc.vanderbilt.edu/git/lab/parse-edi) (Configurable electronic data interchange (EDI) parser for Healthcare **(x12 837 and 835)**. Is it that you searching? Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks @vovakirdan i am searching for the same. But i don't have idea how to use this. So can you please share any snippet regarding this.